# Imputation of missing values - longitudinal data

Tags: self-study, panel-data, missing-data, data-imputation, clinical-trials

When one or more consecutive missing values are surrounded by a same value, how to impute the missing values to that particular value?
As there can be many possible combinations (the number of consecutive missing values, sometimes imputation might be required multiple times in a single row), it seems tedious to handle all the scenarios by hand. Can anyone give me a suggestion for this please

Thanks for your support

Comment: It sounds to me as if you are asking a question not so much about *statistics* as about *statistical programming*. Answers will differ depending on what statistical software package you prefer to use. The main advice I would give is that, whatever software you use to impute the missing values, you should code the imputation in a fully [reproducible](http://reproducibleresearch.net) manner.